# bitbucket push sends file to wrong remote folder

Tags: bitbucket, push

i have a local repo of our company files, on my computer. the main folder where i work is called projectName/ncFiles/files-mgmt2.0.
files-mgmt2.0 is intitialized via "git init".
in files-mgmt2.0, i have a file named: am_action_edit.php.

my bash command prompt shows:

```
DParham@ncFiles MINGW64 /c/Data1/DEVELOPMENT/CompanyName/REPOS/projectName/ncFiles/files-mgmt2.0 (master)
```

"git remote --verbose" shows:

```
origin  git@bitbucket.org:CompanyName/projectName.git (fetch)
origin  git@bitbucket.org:CompanyName/projectName.git (push)
```

when i want to push up the file to the remote bitbucket.org repo, i do it like this, from files-mgmt2.0 folder:

```
git add am_action_editcad.php
git commit -m "add file count next to history button" am_action_edit.php
git push origin
```

that pushes the file to remote: projectName.
**NOTE** that it does NOT push the file to projectName/ncFiles/files-mgmt2.0.

i tried the remote origin command:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/my-github-username/projectName/ncFiles/files-mgmt2.0.git
```

and i got the message, "remote origin already exists."

when i push a file from local: projectName/ncFiles/files-mgmt2.0, i want the file to go to remote: projectName/ncFiles/files-mgmt2.0 folder.

any ideas why it does not push the file "am_action_edit.php" to its **respective** remote folder "files-mgmt2.0"?

Answer (score 2):

You ran `git init` in the `files-mgmt2.0` folder, so that folder is the root of the repository. If you want `projectName` to be the root of the repository then you'll need to initialize the repository from there.

Comment: Jim - yes i did initialize that folder. In case i misunderstood, i will reiterate in different words; then tell me if this helps us address the issue - why  does the push not send the file to its respective folder? It is like the local file is here: a/b/c/file.php, and git init was run in folder c, yet the push sends the file to folder a. Why does the push not send it such that it lands in remote a/b/c/file.php?

Comment: The entire problem is that you ran `git init` in c. Git doesn't care that the remote path doesn't match the local path, or what the full local path is - it only cares about the .git folder and everything associated with it.

As long as you have a .git folder in files-mgmt2.0, this will be an issue for you.

Comment: oh my - so then, i deleted .git from "c", and tried from the root folder "a" which has a .git in it, and tried adding: git add a/b/c/test.php. i got the message, "C:Data1/Development/companyname/repos/a/b/c/test.php is outside repository." so, i did git init again in "c" - and it will not allow the push - says, "could not read from remote repo...make sure you have access rights" - it is broken now. seems like it should be so simple. ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding, your remote repository name is `projectName` and locally you have folders `projectName/ncFiles/files-mgmt2.0`

After you run `git init` under folder `files-mgmt2.0` locally, you added your local existing repo to remote Bitbucket repo and push local commits to remote.

Everything looks good to me.

For the link you posted:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/my-github-username/projectName/ncFiles/files-mgmt2.0.git
```

The remote repository name should be `projectName/ncFiles/files-mgmt2.0` other than `files-mgmt2.0`.**The Strange part is the base link is from GitHub other than Bitbucket.  Are you messing up your repositories???**

Comment: Haifeng, you understand correctly my set up. And to clarify, the repo is projectName/ncFiles/files-mgmt2.0. Or perhaps better yet [from my above response] - it is like the file is here: a/b/c/file.php. I ran git init in folder c, locally. Yet when i push, the file ends up here in my remote repo: a/file.php.

Comment: sorry, Haifeng, i ignored a part of your question. GitHub is associated with my personal email address, not my work account; so, that is odd to me, too! but i looked in github and see nothing from this work account in there.

Answer (score 0):

thx, Jim and Haifeng - i burdened you with intricacies of a messed up set of folders; never figured it out, but instead renamed the folder, cloned down the repo, and things add/commit/push properly even without any ssh key hassle. i appreciate your answers, they helped push me towards the wisdom of "sometimes things are so screwed up, it's best to start over".